# Flutter - Reference Service file from another plugin into the app's manifest file

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, android-manifest

I made the plugin in flutter which defines a service for the app. for e.g. `MyFirebaseMessagingService`.

As we all know we need to reference it from AndroidManifest.xml.
I tried to define the service inside the plugin's AndroidManifest and included this plugin into the application, when I built the application this does not invoke.

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false" android:directBootAware="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Other than that I tried to reference `.MyFirebaseMessagingService` from the application's `AndroidMainfiest` like so: `com.example.myPlugin.MyfirebaseMessagingService` but it can't see it.

So THE QUESTION IS, if there is a way to make application use the services from the plugin ?